# cant join chat from a file (pyrogram)

Tags: python, hyperlink, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Im trying to join in telegram group chats from a txt file that contains lots of group links using Pyrogram framework.
this is my code:

```
links = open('.../Desktop/Tel_Links/Links.txt')

app = Client(
    "My_Account",
    api_id = API,
    api_hash ="API_Hash"
)

with app:
    for line in links.readline():
            app.join_chat()
```

but when i do that i get this error :

```
Exception has occurred: UsernameInvalid
[400 USERNAME_INVALID]: The username is invalid (caused by "contacts.ResolveUsername")
```

after this i tried to type the link in **app.join_chat("link")** instead of app.join_chat(links.readline())

like this :

```
app = Client(
    "My_Account",
    api_id = API,
    api_hash ="API_Hash"
)

with app:
    app.join_chat('django')
```

and that worked perfectly **but** i dont want to add all of them by hand cuz there is lots of links and i need to import them from the file.
please help me
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to pass `line` to join_chat:

```
with app:
    for line in links.readlines():
            app.join_chat(line.rstrip()) # pass line to method
```

You have to remove the trailing newline with rstrip before passing it.

### Edit

Btw: It should be `readlines()` instead of `readline()` in your case.